# Firebase storage limit video seconds

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Is there a way to limit video seconds in firebase storage?
For example if user uploaded 30 seconds video, then disable uploading video or cut at 15 seconds. 
Is this possible?

Comment: Are you asking to stop a storage commit server-side by reading the streamed-data?  Instead of just using a client library to preprocess the video before upload, you want to do it server-side?

Comment: Yeah I meant server-side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Storage has no knowledge of the content type you store. If you upload video to it, it doesn't parse the video in any way. So it can't reject (or truncate) the upload after a certain video duration has been uploaded.

All it can do is reject based on the size of the upload, as shown in the [Firebase documentation on server-side security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/secure-files):

```
 // Allow write files to the path "images/*", subject to the constraints:
 // 1) File is less than 5MB
 // 2) Content type is an image
 // 3) Uploaded content type matches existing content type
 // 4) File name (stored in imageId wildcard variable) is less than 32 characters
 match /{imageId} {
   allow write: if request.resource.size < 5 * 1024 * 1024
                && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*')
                && request.resource.contentType == resource.contentType
                && imageId.size() < 32
```

If you want something more specific, you will have to:

- Do the filtering in the client-side code, possibly in addition to putting a size-limit in the server-side security rules.
- You may also want to do post-processing the video files in server-side code, or in Cloud Functions. The closest example I have is a [Cloud Function that generates thumbnails of uploaded images](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/thumbnails).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I’ll go with that. Also can I get error message or something if uploaded video is over size?

Comment: You'll get a generic "permission denied". That message is intentionally vague, and can not be changed.

Comment: All right thank you for your help everything is clear now!